# hive command in bash script won't load file into table

Tags: file, hive, parseexception

I am writing a bash script that - among other things - has to create a hive table and load a csv file (whose name is not known a priori) into that table.
I have exported the name of the file `foo.csv` into the environment variable `myfile` and have tried the command

```
hive --hiveconf mf=$myfile -e 'set mf; set hiveconf:mf; load data local inpath ${hiveconf:mf} into table mytable'
```

It returns the error

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:23 mismatched input 'foo' expecting StringLiteral near 'inpath' in load statement
```

I already tried using the absolute path to the file and it won't work either: if the path is `/mypath/foo.csv` the error will be

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:23 mismatched input '/' expecting StringLiteral near 'inpath' in load statement
```

Even trying to directly put the file name like this

```
hive -e 'load data local inpath foo.csv into table mytable'
```

doesn't work at all, and the thrown error is the same as before.

Does anybody have any idea on what is wrong with these commands? I could *really* appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Filename should be placed inside `''` :

```
load data local inpath 'foo.csv' into table mytable
```

In your script you should probably escape these symbols so you won't get another parse exception.

Also, look at [Language Manual on loading](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables)