# What does "expected StringLiteral" mean in HIVE?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I cannot figure out why HIVE is throwing me an error in the following script:

```
use <output_db>

drop table if exists <new_tbl>; 
create table <new_tbl> like <old_tbl>;

load data local inpath <directory> into table <new_tbl>;​
```

The exception is:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 4:23 mismatched input '<directory>' expecting StringLiteral near 'inpath' in load statement
```

Sorry if this is an elementary question.  But I've copied it from similar hql statements that work and I can't find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: did you actually put the name of the path in the quotes? like '<directory>'?

Comment: no I did not do that

Comment: well, that is the answer for your question. It is actually in one of the examples here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted

Comment: I also gone through this where in Load statement some special character was there coz I copied from somewhere so wrote manually in Hive Shell this load statement.. And it worked..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hive command in bash script won't load file into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663858/hive-command-in-bash-script-wont-load-file-into-table)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this :
*load data local inpath **directory** into table*

should be :
*load data local inpath **'directory'** into table*

Enclosed within single quotes.

Hope it helps...!!!