# Unable to load hive (beeline table) |StringLiteral near 'inpath' in load statement

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I am trying to load table from HDFS file using beeline. I have written shell script for it which takes StagingSchema.hql file as input and loads table.

```
load data  inpath ${hivevar:dataLocation} into table ${hivevar:sourceTable};
```

Inside Shell script

```
HIVE_DATA_LOCATION="hdfs:///app/data/empRecord.csv"

beeline -u $BEELINE_JDBC_URL -n $BEELINE_USERNAME -p $BEELINE_PASSWORD --hivevar sourceTable=$SOURCE_TABLE --hivevar dataLocation=$HIVE_DATA_LOCATION --silent=true -f StagingSchema.hql
```

While running above script , i am getting below exception

```
    WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.

Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:23 mismatched input 'hdfs' expecting StringLiteral near 'inpath' in load statement (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Any pointers on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hive command in bash script won't load file into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663858/hive-command-in-bash-script-wont-load-file-into-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try covering inpath within single quotes in the load statement,

load data inpath '${hivevar:dataLocation}' into table ${hivevar:sourceTable};